# URL Form Encoded special German Characters between AngularJS and Jackson Backend

Tags: spring, encoding, angularjs, jackson

I have an AngularJS Frontend and a Spring MVC Backend with Jackson to take care of the Serialization and JS<->Java conversion

When i pass German characters like "ö, ä, ü, ß" to my backend via http body payload, there is no problem. I have the header "Content-Type" "application/json;charset=UTF-8" and all works fine.
But if i have those characters in my url angular encodes them. This is fine however it encodes them a different way that jackson tries to decode i believe.

Here is what Angular makes out of "höhe": h%C3%B6he
I believe Jackson expects: h%f6he

I think this is because UTF8 is 2 byte while ASCII is 1 byte encoding. However is there a setting for either Jackson or Angular to "speak the same encoding language"?

Thanks for any help!
Kind regards,
Pascal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jackson does not handle URL decoding, as it requires an input source such as `InputStream` or `String`: it is most likely that the Servlet container (Jetty?) that service runs on handles this. One problem is that definition of which encoding URL should use is... well, poorly defined really: "Content-Type" does NOT define this (it's just for payload).

So you need to figure out how to make servlet container and client have shared understanding of what encoding is to be used (difference in your case looks like UTF-8 vs Latin-1).
Or: if you can make client escape all non-ASCII characters with JSON escape sequences, that will also work.